# Can I move the Angular 5 project file from c drive to d or e drive manually?

Tags: angular5

I have installed Angular 5 project folder via npm Angular CLI in my computer's c drive. Now I want to move that folder to d or e drive manually. Can I...

Answer (score 0):

@Bulbul

Yes you can move the complete folder to the other drive.
After moving it, try running npm install and ng serve to check it works fine.